# Find $\dim_k(m/m^2)$ in a local ring without geometric interpretation.

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, affine-varieties

I have the following question:

Let $V$ be an irreducible affine variety over an algebraically closed field $K$. For any point $p \in V$, the ring $P(V) := ${$f \in K(V) |
f$ is regular at $p$} is local. Denote by $M_p$ the maximal ideal of $P(V)$.
Let $V = V (y − x^2) \subseteq K^2$ and $p = (0, 0)$. Show that $\dim_K (M_p/M_p^2)$
is $1$.

I have come across a way this can be solved using a geometric interpretation where $M_p/M_p^2$ is the dimension of the tangent space to $V$ at $p$. However I think that is outside the scope of my course, and I find it difficult to prove that way.

I believe I am missing something simple here. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Comment: 1. Please use MathJax for all of your math. 2. You can just take the quotient - can you write down what $M_p$ is and what $M_p^2$ is?

Comment: Yo @HankScorpio could you define what $M_p$ is. I'm battling with that part.

Comment: As per your post, it's the maximal ideal of $P(V)$.